# Show that the $\max{ \{ x,y \} }= \frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

Show that the $\max{ \{ x,y \} }= \dfrac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$.

I do not understand how to go about completing this problem or even where to start.

Comment: It may help to note that $|x| = \max(x,-x)$.

Comment: I would start by convincing yourself that the proof is meaningful with several concrete examples. Set x=1, y=-3, for example, and try to get an intuition *that* it's true (before you try to prove *why* it's true). Then many of the comments above should be helpful.

Comment: Just do a case-by-case analysis: Evaluate both sides once for the case $x\leq y$ and once for $y\leq x$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof the maximum function $\max(x,y) = \frac {x +y +|x-y|} {2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457177/proof-the-maximum-function-maxx-y-frac-x-y-x-y-2)

Comment: @TuckerRapu: IIRC, here and in a couple of other places you've marked an older question as a duplicate of a newer question.

Comment: To those reviewing for closure: DO NOT close this question. The "original" for which this is a duplicate is a newer question.

Answer (score 63):

Here is another way of looking at it:

We have $|x| = \max(x,-x)$. Also, $\max(a,b)+c = \max(a+c,b+c)$, and if $c \geq 0$, then $c \max(a,b) = \max(ac,bc)$.

Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}(x+y+|x-y|) &=& \frac{1}{2}(x+y+\max(x-y,y-x)) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(\max(x-y+x+y,y-x+x+y)) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(\max(2x,2y)) \\
&=& \max(x,y)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: +1 it would be nice, if you noted the $\text{min}(x,y)$ for the OP as well. :)

Comment: @BabakS.: Thanks! The $\min$ result follows immediately from $\max(x,y)+\min(x,y) = x+y$.

Comment: Great! This should be accepted!

Comment: on the first line why is it max(x-y,y-x) and not max(x-y,-x-y)?

Comment: @AGarza Because $|z|=\max(z,-z)$. Now let $z=x-y$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 38):

This probably isn't as rigorous as it should be, but I think it's intuitive enough.

Hmm... We don't know which of $x$ or $y$ is bigger, but we do know one thing: their average.  If we call the average $z$, then $z=\frac{x+y}{2}$. Now, the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $|x-y|$, so the distance from $z$ to both $x$ and $y$ is $\frac{|x-y|}{2}$.

So if we imagine a number line, the distance from $0$ to $z$ is $\frac{x+y}{2}$, and the distance from $z$ to max(x, y) is $\frac{|x-y|}{2}$. Thus, the total distance from $0$ to max(x, y) is $\frac{|x-y|}{2}$ + $\frac{x+y}{2}$, as desired.

Comment: I like this answer. If not as rigorous, this is exactly how one would come up with the expression in the first place. Also, one can easily come up with similar expression for $\operatorname{min}$ in this manner.

Answer (score 31):

**Hint:** If $x\ge y$ then $|x-y|=x-y$. If $x\lt y$ then $|x-y|=-(x-y)=y-x$.

We have used the fact that in general $|w|=w$ if $w\ge 0$ and $|w|=-w$ if $w\lt 0$.

Comment: +1 This is the most straightforward one here. Also @user71925 it should also be noted that $\min\{x,y\} = \frac{1}{2}(x+y-|x-y|)$.

Comment: I think I mistakenly hit the downvote button here but it won't let me undo it. My apologies, entirely unintended.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\max\{x,y\} =\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}
$$
$$
=> 2.\max\{x,y\} =x+y+|x-y|
$$
there are two possible situation : 
1.  $ y>x $, i.e $\max\{x,y\}=y$ then $y-x=|x-y|$, this equation is true because we assume that
$ y>x$ 
2. $x>y$, or $\max\{x,y\}=x$, then $x-y=|x-y|$, which is true if $x>y$

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, focus on $|x-y|$ as the absolute difference of the two numbers.

Without loss of generality, assume $x > y$.  Then $y + |x - y| = x$.   This can be understood as representing that if we add the difference between two numbers to the smaller, we get the larger.

The specific equation will naturally fall out with this observation.

Answer (score 1):

For another approach we can do as follows:

$$max(x, y) - max(-x, -y) = x + y$$
and,
$$max(x, y) + max(-x, -y) = |x - y|$$

Adding those together yeilds:
$$2\times max(x, y) = x + y + |x - y|$$
Dividing by two, gives us what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, let $y=x+k$ for some nonnegative number $k$. Then,

$$
\frac{x+(x+k)+|x-(x+k)|}{2} = \frac{2x+2k}{2} = x+k = y
$$

which is equal to $\max(x,y)$ by the assumption.