# Proof the maximum function $\max(x,y) = \frac {x +y +|x-y|} {2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

I want to prove the maximum function max: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is defined by

$$\max(x,y) = \begin{cases}x,  \text { if }  x \geq y , \\ y,  \text { if }  x < y \end{cases}$$

I want to prove this for 
$\max(x,y) =   \frac {x +y +|x-y|} {2}$.

I have no idea on how to start, I just read over my search over the internet that the modulus function could be a way. I really appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**

I want to prove that $\max(x,y) =   \frac {x +y +|x-y|} {2}$.

Comment: Make a case distinction, $x \geqslant y$ and $x < y$.

Comment: You want "to prove the maximum function"? What does this mean? What exactly do  you want?

Comment: you mean just like: $x \geq   \frac {x +y +|x-y|} {2}$

Comment: mgelius note my edit

Comment: @what'sup: I don't understand the purpose of using `\Large` everywhere.

Comment: Oh, the last part of the edit clears things. Thanks.

Comment: i don't know but i like it large

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If ${x \geq y}$ then $\max(x,y)=x$ and $${\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}=\frac{x+y+x-y}{2}=\frac{2x}{2}=x}.$$

Else, then ${\max(x,y)=y}$ and $${\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}=\frac{x+y+y-x}{2}=\frac{2y}{2}=y}.$$

Thus, ${\max(x,y)=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}}$.