# Pointwise maximum: translation and scaling

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633071/absolute-value-and-max-min-function-why-a-b-a-b-2-maxa-b) question, I am getting that $2\times \max(a,b) = \max(2a,2b)$, and more generally, $c\times \max(a,b) = \max(c\times a, c\times b)$ for $c\geq0$, since we have
$$
\begin{align*}
a + b + |a-b| &= a+b + \max(a-b, b-a) \\
&= \max\big[(a+b) + a-b),\; (a+b) + b-a\big] \\
&= \max(2a,2b))\\
a + b + |a-b| &= \big[\max(a,b) + \min(a,b)\big] + \big[\max(a,b) - \min(a,b)\big] \\
&= 2\max(a,b)
\end{align*}
$$

Is this correct? It feels odd to move $(a+b)$ into the max in the first line. This seems to indicate that for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by the pointwise max
$$f(x) := \max(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$$
satisfies $f(c\times x + d) = cf(x) + d$ for $c\geq0$ and $d$ a (specific?) linear combination of $x$. For $d$ a constant scalar, we have that $f$ some translation and scaling properties (not sure what this is called), which is intuitive, but is this right for $d = d(x)$ some linear combination of $x$?

What operations are allowed for moving terms in and out of $\max(\cdot)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $c\times x$ when $x$ is a high dimension vector?

Comment: I mean a scalar $c$ multiplied componentwise to $x$

Comment: and add $d$ componentwise as well?

Comment: yes, thanks, when $d$ is a scalar added componentwise

Comment: So it'd be linear if we had $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ (together with $f(cx) = cf(x)$), but we only have something less: for $y \equiv (1,1,\ldots,1) \cdot L$ for a scalar  $L$. Does this property have a name?

Comment: You don't have linearity since $c$ must be nonnegative.// $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is not correct.

Comment: but we also don't have additivity $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, right? for example, $max(1 + -1,-1+ 1) = 0 \neq \max(1,-1) + \max(-1,1)$

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: I have not seen a name for such property. Maybe it is not interesting enough to have a name. People give a specific name to a certain concept for some *purposes*; not for sake of just having a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things too complicated.

It is simply that $a\ge b$ if and only if $2a\ge 2b$; so

when $a\ge b$,
$$
LHS=2\cdot a=2a=\max(2a,2b)
$$

and when $a<b$,
$$
LHS=2\cdot b=2b=\max(2a,2b)
$$

If you want to apply the  formula that
$$
\max(x,y)=\frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}
$$
then it is simply
$$
2\max(x,y)=\frac{2x+2y-2|x-y|}{2}=\frac{2x+2y-|2x-2y|}{2}=\max(2x,2y)
$$

---

Added.

Okay, after fixing the typos, in your approach, you have
$$
\begin{align}
a+b+|a-b|
&=a+b+\max(a-b,b-a)\\
&=\max(a-b+(a+b),b-a+(a+b))\\
&=\max(2a,2b)
\end{align}
$$

In particular, it is correct that
$$
a+b+\max(a-b,b-a)
=\max(a-b+(a+b),b-a+(a+b))
$$
because
$$
\max(x,y)+L=\max(x+L,y+L)
$$
since $x\ge y$ if and only if $x+L\ge y+L$.

---

In general, if you have $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_2)$ and $c\ge 0$, you have
$$
c\max(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\max(cx_1,\cdots,cx_n)
$$

So $f(cx)=cf(x)$.

On the other hand, for any $L\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\max(x_1+L,\cdots,x_n+L)=\max(x_1,\cdots,x_n)+L
$$
Combining together,
$$
\max(cx_1+L,\cdots,cx_n+L)=c\max(x_1,\cdots,x_n)+L
$$

Comment: I see, thank you. Is it fine to move (a+b) into the max?

Comment: @jjjjjj Your expression $\max((a+b)+a-b)$ does not make sense; the function $\max$ has two arguments.

Comment: Oh sorry, typo, let me fix what i meant. thanks

Comment: @jjjjjj: yes, that is correct then.

Comment: got it, and that's just because $a \geq b \iff a + (a+b) \geq b + (a+b)$. So it feels like there's something close to linearity, but i'm not seeing the place it breaks down; e.g., for "max(0,x)" linearity breaks at 0.

Comment: thanks, i've upvoted, still trying to figure out how the pointwise max isn't "linear", specifically the (×+)=()+  part or how that relates to linearity

Comment: @jjjjjj please see my edits.

Comment: thanks very much. before accepting, does the property you detail have a name? it seems close to linearity, but not quite.

Comment: @jjjjjj it is far from linearity. Note in particular that $c\ge 0$.

Comment: and nonnegative homogeneous?