# proof-writing suggestions of my proof of $\max(f(n), g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, computational-complexity

Q: $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are asymptotically non-negative functions. prove that $\max(f(n), g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

my proof as follows:

If $\exists n_0$ such that $f(n)\geq g(n)\geq 0$ $\forall n \geq n_0$, then
$$0\leq\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+g(n))\leq f(n)=\max(f(n),g(n)) \leq 1(f(n)+g(n))$$

If $\exists n_0$ such that $g(n)> f(n) \geq 0$ $\forall n \geq n_0$, then
$$0\leq\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+g(n))\leq g(n)=\max(f(n),g(n)) \leq 1(f(n)+g(n))$$

Thus, by $\Theta$ definition, $\max(f(n), g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

I am not sure whether my proof is rigorously enough and logically correct.

Can I suppose or assume "if $\exists n_0$ ..." in the above-mentioned proof?

Comment: What if there is no such $n_0$? What if $f-g$ changes sign infinitely often? This can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429622